# Generalized homology theories and coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology

So reading through Hatcher I was wondering what is the importance of the coefficient groups in the generalized reduced homology theory, and how do they relate to the given homology theory. In other words if we have a reduced homology theory $\tilde{h}$ on $Top^{CW}$. Such that $\tilde{h}_n(S^0)=G_n$ for abelian groups $G_n$, how do they relate to $\tilde{h}_n(X)$ for an arbitrary CW complex $X$. In other words how do the homologies of $S^0$ relate to other homologies in the given homology theory if the dimension axiom is dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role of spheres, in the context of CW complexes, is that they generate all generalized CW complexes under taking certain (homotopy) colimits.  So given any functor $F$ that behaves predictably with respect to such colimits (think excision or Mayer-Vietoris), the value of $F$ on any CW complex is essentially determined by those on spheres.  Concretely, this is demonstrated by cellular homology.  By knowing the value of the homology theory on spheres together with how a CW complex $X$ is built up from spheres (think attaching maps), we can compute the homology of $X$.

This story doesn't really change if the dimension axiom is dropped.  You can still filter a CW complex $X$ by its CW skeleta (so its associated graded are bouquets of spheres), compute the generalized homology of these spheres, and then try to reassemble from these pieces the generalized homology of $X$ via knowledge of attaching maps and other things.  The main difference is that this "reassembly" procedure is slightly more complicated, because if the (reduced) homology of spheres is not concentrated in a single degree, then they can contribute to, and interfere with, other parts of the associated graded.  All this information is packaged homologically into something called the *Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence*, which looks like $$E^2_{s,t} = H_s^\text{cell}(X; h_t) \Rightarrow h_{s+t}(X),$$ where $h$ is a generalized homology theory.  Here, the value of $h$ on spheres appears as the coefficients with respect to which you take homology to obtain the $E^2$ page.  For example, if $h$ is ordinary homology, the spectral sequence degenerates and this just says cellular homology computes ordinary homology.

I hope this answers your question about one can use the generalized homology of spheres to compute (in principle) the generalized homology of any CW complex.